# Expression: " you [something] you"

Tags: meaning, expressions

Can you explain the grammar of this expression and in what situations it can be used?

"you [something] you"

E.g. Get away from me *you filthy woman you*.

Comment: The *OED* attributes an early use to Shakespeare in *Midsummer Night's Dream*: "Fy, fy, you counterfait, you puppet, you."

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen this construction discussed.  It appears to be a vocative that may occur at the end of a root sentence. A vocative expression refers to a person to whom something is said by the speaker of the sentence.  A root sentence is a sentence which cannot be a constituent within another sentence other than a direct quotation.  (The notion of "root sentence" is due to the linguist Joseph Emonds.)